# PhoneGap Build and local development

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, mobile, phonegap-build

I'm creating an Application which will be packaged for different platforms using PhoneGap Build.
Now my project structure looks like:

```
+--- css
+--- img
+--- js
+--- res
+--- config.xml
+--- icon.png
\--- index.html
```

This is pretty standard following PhoneGap's starter project.
I'm able to upload this as a zip file to the PhoneGap Build server and get back the packages.

Now I wonder how I should best do some local development (without building through PhoneGap Build after every change); should I create a 'normal' PhoneGap project in a separate folder and place the files in my project assets (html, js, css, img)?
This normal PhoneGap project I can run via e.g. Xcode.

I wonder if above is best approach or there are alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

They have a feature called hydration that may speed the test process, but you still have to go through an upload and build step. https://build.phonegap.com/docs/hydration

If you can get away without the apis, then it is very easy to develop and test locally, just opening in your local browser. This is faster than recompiling and deploying to a local simulator. If you only need a few APIs, you may consider stubbing out the apis. This also makes it much easier to write automated tests for your code.

Another option is using the phonegap emulator chrome plugin. http://emulate.phonegap.com/ This can simulate phonegap apis.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried one of those:

1. **Chrome:** If you don’t need PhoneGap APIs for your development, you can simply use Chrome with "Emulate touch events" enabled. I use this a lot, because most of the time I work on CSS and JavaScript and therefore can perfectly use Chrome alone. Setting "Device metric" is a nice helper, too.
2. **iPhone Simulator:** If you work on a Mac, you can use the iPhone Simulator and inspect your project with Safari.
3. **Ripple emulator:** To emulate the PhoneGap APIs you can use this emulator: http://emulate.phonegap.com/

As long as you develop mostly plain HTML, CSS and JavaScript, this setup may help you to be more productive. I think that is what @simap has meant with 'developing on localhost'.